# Unidirectional association with type in join table

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, entity-relationship

I have 3 tables: Person -> Person_Address_Type {person_address_type_id(PK), person_id, address_id, type} -> Address. The Person_Address_Type is to indicate the type of the relationship between Person and addresses. For example:

```
Mr. A has unique HOME addresses.
Mr. A has one or many OFFICE addresses.
Mr. A has one or many RELAXING addresses.
... And other types of address may be added later.
```

How can I make the mapping with Hibernate to have below java entity:

```
Person {
     getHomeAddress(): Address;
     getOfficeAddresses(): Address*;
     getRelaxingAddresses(): Address*;
}
```

I know about having transient fields. However, we can't do HQL query with transient. I need a mapping.
How can I make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping should be like this

***Table Structure***

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
    `id_person` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `birth_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cell_phone` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_person`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `address_type` (
    `id_address_type` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_address_type`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `address` (
    `id_address` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fk_address_type`BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_address`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ADDRESS_TYPE` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_address_type`) REFERENCES `address_type` (`id_address_type`),
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `person_address` (
    `id_person_address` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `fk_person` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fk_address`BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,       
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_person_address`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_PERSON` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_person`) REFERENCES `person` (`id_person`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ADDRESS` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_address`) REFERENCES `address` (`id_address`)  
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

***Entity Classes***

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person",uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id_person")})
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154676L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_person", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="person_address", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_person", referencedColumnName="id_person")}
    , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_address", referencedColumnName="id_address")})
    private Set<Address> address;

   // Getter and Setter methods 
}
```

**Address.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id_address")})
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6790693372846798580L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_address", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer addressId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="address", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private AddressType addressType;    

   // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

***AddressType.java***

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address_type",uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id_address_type")})
public class AddressType {
     
    @Id
    @Column(name="id_address_type", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long addressTypeId;



    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Address address;    

    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

now when you call `getAddress()` this will return all the address related to Person then group this address according to there address type i.e. by calling `address.getAddressType().getName()` method.

You can also have @ManyToMany mapping between Address and AddressType entities

Comment: Sorry. The most important map I want to see is the getters in the Person class (getHomeAddress(): getOfficeAddresses(): Address*...). However, they are not here.

Answer (score 0):

from my bare knowledge of Hibernate, seems that the style of relationship table is not directly supported in Hibernate.

The easiest way is to create separate views of your `Person_Address_Type`, so that you have 3 relationship tables like: `PERSON_HOME_ADDRESS`, `PERSON_OFFICE_ADDRESS`, `PERSON_RELAX_ADDRESS` etc.

Each of the view just contains `PERSON_ID` and `ADDRESS_ID`

With these views, you can do a normal `ManyToMany/ManyToOne` with `JoinTable`.

However this approach may not work if you want to update the relationships directly using these entities (depending on DBMS, some DBMS allow update/insert through views).

Another way is creating a new entity, like `PersonAddressRelationship`, which contains ref to Person, Address and a RelationshipType enum.

Then the three relationships in Person to Address is not directly mapped.  Instead, you populate the value of `homeAddress`, `relaxAddresses` and `officeAddresses` in `@PostLoad` method, base on your mapped `addressRelationships`.  (and update the `addressRelationships` base on `homeAddress`, `relaxAddresses` and `officeAddresses` in `@PrePersist` method too)

Answer (score 0):

I have just found that @WhereJoinTable is for this (just in theory, I haven't tried in practice)